# how to make a dynamic roles in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I am a begginer, I would like to know if is possible to transform a roles in dynamic role like the @Route  model.

```
/**
 * @IsGranted("ROLE_{dance}_{level}") 
 * @Route("/{dance}/{level}", name="danceLevel")
 */
```

I have a project to make a website with some restrictions to accees to the content and I would like to throught by a interface like "easy Admin" to create a new category of dance and level that will be transform in role automaticaly
thanks by advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security annotations would be for statically named roles and other permissions (checked by Voters).

You would be able to do more dynamic checks with:

```
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted("ROLE_{$dance}_{$level}", $user, 'No access');
```

It's possible that a Security voter would be able to simplify the checks to what would be a static name and so used in @IsGranted (Or, it could for example, get the current $request, via the RequestStack service, to get `dance` and `level` parameters, if required).